# UnicodeEncodeError in Django

Tags: python, django

I tried to load a page in my app, and the below error pop up. I'm using tweepy to connect to twitter. And I don't know where the error come from or the line I need to fix. Would love to know how I can solve this.

```
  UnicodeEncodeError at /test/

   'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 6: character maps to   <undefined>

   Request Method:      GET
   Request URL:     http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/
   Django Version:  1.3.1
   Exception Type:  UnicodeEncodeError
   Exception Value: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 6: character maps to <undefined>
  Exception Location:   C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py in encode, line 12
  Python Executable:    C:\Python27\python.exe
  Python Version:   2.7.2
```

Views.py

```
  def testdat(request):
      if request.method=="GET":
         treats=Cursor(api.list_timeline, owner=request.user, slug="").items(20)
         for treat in treats:
             print "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (treat.text,
                                  treat.author.screen_name,
                                  treat.created_at,
                                  treat.source,)
             top=Twet(text= treat.text, author_screen_name= treat.author.screen_name, created_at= treat.created_at, source= treat.source)
             top.save()
        treats=Cursor(api.list_timeline, owner=request.user, slug='').items(20)
        return render_to_response('dashy.html',{'treats': treats},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop printing. Figure out a different way of doing your debugging. Or, encode to UTF-8 first.